# Error en la respuesta de REst en java, objeto no se muestra correctamente

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Buenos dias, tengo un problema con las respuesta de servicios rest en java , he usado un generico con tipo object para estandarizar las respuestas pero caundo le agrego a objectos a este objeto y se convierte en Json no se convierte bien , este es el objeto:

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private Object data;
    private Long numero_reg;

    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numero_reg
     */
    public long getNumero_reg() {
        return numero_reg;
    }

    /**
     * @param numero_reg the numero_reg to set
     */
    public void setNumero_reg(long numero_reg) {
        this.numero_reg = numero_reg;
    }

}
```

Este es el rest que usa como ejemplo para ver si funciona o no :

```
@Path("/pruebas")
public class Pruebita {
    @GET
    public SigepData getalgo(){
        ObjectoDatos od=new ObjectoDatos();
        od.setPrueba("hola");
        od.setPrueba2("hola2");
        Data sd=new SigepData();
        sd.setData(od);
        sd.setNumero_reg(1);
        return sd;
    }
}
```

pero el resultado que se muestra en ves de mostrar el ObjetoDatos se muestra su nombre de instancia como si en ves de mostrar el objeto mostrar el toString que no es lo que uno quiere en la respuesta.

```
{"data":"bo.ObjectoDatos@6d858b63","numero_reg":1}
```

por favor alguien tiene alguna idea como hacer para que lo mapee a json correctamente?

la unica forma de hacer funcionar ha sido:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Data implements Serializable {
    private ObjectoDatos data;
    private Long numero_reg;

    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public ObjectoDatos getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(ObjectoDatos data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numero_reg
     */
    public long getNumero_reg() {
        return numero_reg;
    }

    /**
     * @param numero_reg the numero_reg to set
     */
    public void setNumero_reg(long numero_reg) {
        this.numero_reg = numero_reg;
    }

}
```

es decir cambiando Object por ObjetoDatos y en ese caso si el rest ya devuelve bien :

{"data":{"prueba":"hola","prueba2":"hola2"},"numero_reg":1}

pero no puedo hacer eso en el sistema que estoy desarrollando ya que Data tendria que ser muchos objetos y no se puede utilizar para otros, tambien he probado utilizar genericos T , ahi tube el problema de que no se que tipo pasarle para probar hardcodeando puse el tipo ObjectoDatos  pero tampoco es el mismo problema del comienzo no lo reconoce y llama al toString, como ven el tostring no es el problema, si no que no reconoce el tipo a convertir a json, y como no puede lo que hace es llamar al objeto toString y mostrar eso en el json , pero como ven si especifico el objeto si funciona , por lo que se que no es el toString si no el tipeado y mapeado del json

Comment: Si he entendido bien el REST te responde esto: `{"data":"bo.ObjectoDatos@6d858b63","numero_reg":1}`. Se trata de un JSON correcto, en toda regla. Lo único que tienes que hacer es tomar la respuesta y parsearla o tratarla a través de una clase que represente **esa entidad** en tu programa, o sea, una clase que tenga todos los campos que vienen en el JSON. **[Java tiene su propia API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)  para tratar los objetos JSON**, me pregunto ¿no estarás intentando inventar la rueda?

Comment: hola si el rest responde {"data":"bo.ObjectoDatos@6d858b63","numero_reg":1} pero deberia responder : {"data":{"prueba":"hola","prueba2":"hola2"},"numero_reg":1} como veras  {"data":"bo.ObjectoDatos@6d858b63","numero_reg":1} no se puede parsear porque no tiene los datos es un texto

Comment: y no no esto reinventando la rueda , es un sistema con cientosd e objetos diferentes la idea es standarizar la respuesta con un "tag" standar que tengan todossss las respuestas.

Comment: Esto `bo.ObjectoDatos@6d858b63` indica que al REST posiblemente le falte un `toString` cuando devuelve la variable `data: ...` de la respuesta. Si quien programa el REST eres tú mismo no hay problema, lo puedes corregir y adaptar para que responda como tu quieras, pues la respuesta del REST la construye el programador del mismo, pero si el REST es programado por otra persona no te queda otra alternativa que ponerte en contacto con el programador del REST. Eso no queda claro en tu pregunta. Si la respuesta del REST es la clase que pones arriba, le falta el método `toString`.

Comment: mm y que pondria en el toString? auto mappear el objeto a json? esto no deberia ser automatico por jax rs?? eso es la pregunta , ya que eso me obligaria a que todos los objetos que se devuelvan tengan este codigo

Comment: si pongo a :public class Data implements Serializable {
    private *ObjectoDatos* data;
    private Long numero_reg; entonces eso si funciona porque cuando pongo object no funciona por ahi va la pregunta , si hay que hacer algo configurar algo , etc etc

Comment: Hay herramientas en línea que te ayudan a serializar tus datos, y te sugieren incluso modelos de clase según lo que quieras hacer. [Esta es una de ellas](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) si colocas tu JSON a la izquierda y marcas a la derecha las casillas de lo que quieres te muestra un ejemplo de clase que podrías usar para tu programa.

Comment: definitivamente no has entendido la pregunta pero gracias igual

Comment: O tú no has entendido lo que te comento, o tal vez ni siquiera entiendes el problema que tienes. Si quieres una mejor ayuda te recomiendo que expliques mejor lo que quieres, editando la pregunta. A ver si aparece alguien que pueda ayudarte mejor. Saludos, esperando que encuentres una solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh resuelto casi en su totalidad el problema ya que le objetivo era encerrar el el objeto en un tag especial en este caso data y los numeros de registros se ha utilizado un hashMap como muestra el ejemplo:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Maps;
```

este es el codigo:

```
        Map<String, Object> respuesta = Maps.newHashMap();
        respuesta.put("data", entidad);
        if(nroRegistros != 1) {
            respuesta.put("numero_reg", nroRegistros);                
        }
        return respuesta;
```